# How to tell if a Subject.OfType<T> has any subscribers

Tags: rx.net

So I'm trying to put together a little message bus using Rx.NET.

```
public class Bus {
    private readonly Subject<BaseCommand> _commands = new Subject<BaseComand>();

    public void RegisterHandler<TCommand>(Action<TCommand> handler) where TCommand: BaseCommand {
        _commands
            .OfType&lt;TCommand&gt;()
            .Publish()
            .RefCount()
            .Subscribe(handler);
    }

    public void SendCommand<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand: BaseCommand {
        _commands.OnNext(command);
    }
}
```

So this is the gist of the code. I want to restrict the subscriptions so that only one subscription can exists for a single message type. Is there anyway to check the Observable from `OfType<T>` for any existing subscriptions before adding a new subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like this (I've changed your RegisterHandler to have an IDisposable return type, so you can actually unsubscribe again):

```
public class Bus
{
    private readonly Subject<BaseCommand> _commands = new Subject<BaseCommand>();

    private class Counter<TCommand> where TCommand : BaseCommand
    {
        public static int Count;
    }

    public IDisposable RegisterHandler<TCommand>(Action<TCommand> handler, Action<Exception> OnError = null) where TCommand : BaseCommand
    {
        OnError = OnError ?? (Action<Exception>)((ex) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => {throw ex; })); // alternative case of course only works if dispatcher is available

        return Observable.Create<TCommand>(o =>
        {
            if (Interlocked.Increment(ref Counter<TCommand>.Count) > 1)
            {
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref Counter<TCommand>.Count);
                o.OnError(new InvalidOperationException("Too many subscribers!"));
                return Disposable.Empty;
            }

            var subscription = _commands
                .OfType<TCommand>()
                      .Publish()
                      .RefCount()
                      .Subscribe(o);

            var decrement = Disposable.Create(() =>
            {
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref Counter<TCommand>.Count);
            });

            return new CompositeDisposable(subscription, decrement);
        })
        .Subscribe(handler, OnError);

    }

    public void SendCommand<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : BaseCommand
    {
        _commands.OnNext(command);
    }
}
```

edit: I would probably change the signature of your RegisterHandler function to

```
 public IObservable<TCommand> RegisterHandler<TCommand>() where TCommand : BaseCommand
```

though; saves some hassle with error management (the subscriber will have to take care of that himself), and your consumers are more free in the way when and how they want to subscribe to these events.

Comment: Hmm It's too bad tracking subscription counts aren't supported out of the box. Oh well, thanks!